# is it possible to have async cross-field validators to validate angular form?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to implement an `async` cross-field validator which will fetch some results from my backend.

Here is the relevant part of the component:

```
export class MemberComponent implements OnInit {
    
  private _form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    activity: new FormControl(null),
    account: new FormControl(null),
    role: new FormControl(null),
    fare: new FormControl(null),
    info: new FormControl(null),
  }, {
    validators: new ValidateMemberNotTaken(this._memberService)
  });

  constructor(private _memberService: MemberService){}
  ...
```

Here is my implementation of the validator:

```
export class ValidateMemberNotTaken implements AsyncValidator {
  constructor(private memberService: MemberService) {}

  validate(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {

    const {activity, account, role} = control.value;

    return this.memberService.exists(activity,account,role).pipe(
      map(exists => (exists ? { memberExists: true } : null)),
      catchError(() => of(null))
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the function `exists` used in my validator:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MemberService {

  private _apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/members';

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient,
    ) {
  }

  exists(activityId: number, accountId: number, roleId: number): Observable<boolean> {
    const url = `${this._apiUrl}/activity/${activityId}/account/${accountId}/role/${roleId}`;
    return this._http.get<boolean>(url);
  }
}
```

When compiling my code, I get the following error:

```
Error: src/app/components/member/member.component.ts:31:6 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ validators: ValidateMemberNotTaken; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions'.
```

Is it possible to implement cross-field async validators ? If so could you please tell me what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you are making a class of the Validator, we usually use functions for custom validators (async and sync) and that is what I would suggest:

```ts
export function validateMemberNotTaken(memberService): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (control) {
      const {activity, account, role} = control.value;

      return memberService.exists(activity,account,role).pipe(
        map(exists => (exists ? { memberExists: true } : null)),
        catchError(() => of(null))
      );
    }
    return of(null);
  };
}
```

Import the function and then mark the validator as follows in your formgroup:

```ts
validators: validateMemberNotTaken(this._memberService)
```

Comment: I think the OP got what he/she was doing from the Angular doc here: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#creating-asynchronous-validators